# Moving from Django 1.3 to Django 1.11 object_list

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to update some python files from Django 1.3 to Django 1.11. In the views.py file I have a method with the following line

```
return object_list(request, queryset=results['flips'], extra_context=context, **kwargs)
```

I've read that object_list is now deprecated and instead of that I have to use ListView from `django.views.generic.list` and use Class View.

I've tried with this:

**Django 1.3**

**views.py**

```
def flow(request, **kwargs):
agent = 'default'
lang = request.LANGUAGE_CODE.lower()
cache_key = '%s%s%s' % (request.build_absolute_uri(), request.user.id, lang)
results = cache.get(cache_key)
if results is None:
    results = {}
    flips = pushitem.visibles.visibles().by_lang(lang=lang)
    sort = request.GET.get('sort', '')
    if sort == 'popular':
        flips = flips.order_by('-votes_total')
    else:
        flips = flips.order_by('-timestamp')
    scope = request.GET.get('scope', '')
    if scope:
        today = datetime.now()
        if scope == 'day':
            flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year, timestamp__month=today.month, timestamp__day=today.day)
        if scope == 'month':
            flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year, timestamp__month=today.month)
        if scope == 'year':
            flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year)
    #Todo use UserProfile instead of User for people and add a searchfield to UserProfile (faster)
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        people = User.objects.filter(Q(username__contains=query))
        people |= User.objects.filter(Q(first_name__contains=query))
        people |= User.objects.filter(Q(last_name__contains=query))
        flips = flips.filter(Q(searchfield__contains=query))
        topics = Tag.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=unidecode(query.lower())))
        results['people'] = people
        results['topics'] = topics
    results['flips'] = flips
    cache.set(cache_key, results)
context = {
    'title': _('Flipter.com, Ask everything!'),
    'description': _('The world\'s largest community of opinions, made with awesome polls.')
}
if results.has_key('people'):
    context['people'] = results['people']
if results.has_key('topics'):
    context['topics'] = results['topics']
return object_list(request, queryset=results['flips'], extra_context=context, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', flow, dict(template_name='flow.html', paginate_by=12,), name='flow'),
```

**Django 1.11**

**views.py**
    class FlipView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = 'flow.html'

```
def flow(request, **kwargs):
agent = 'default'
lang = LANGUAGE_CODE.lower()
cache_key = '%s%s%s' % (request.build_absolute_uri(), request.user.id, lang)
results = cache.get(cache_key)
if results is None:
    results = {}
    flips = pushitem.visibles.visibles()
    sort = request.GET.get('sort', '')
    if sort == 'popular':
        flips = flips.order_by('-votes_total')
    else:
        flips = flips.order_by('-timestamp')
    scope = request.GET.get('scope', '')
    if scope:
        today = datetime.now()
        if scope == 'day':
            flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year, timestamp__month=today.month, timestamp__day=today.day)
        if scope == 'month':
            flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year, timestamp__month=today.month)
        if scope == 'year':
            flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year)
    #Todo use UserProfile instead of User for people and add a searchfield to UserProfile (faster)
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        people = User.objects.filter(Q(username__contains=query))
        people |= User.objects.filter(Q(first_name__contains=query))
        people |= User.objects.filter(Q(last_name__contains=query))
        flips = flips.filter(Q(searchfield__contains=query))
        topics = Tag.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=unidecode(query.lower())))
        results['people'] = people
        results['topics'] = topics
    results['flips'] = flips
    cache.set(cache_key, results)
context = {
    'title': _('Flipter.com, Ask everything!'),
    'description': _('The world\'s largest community of opinions, made with awesome polls.')
}
if 'people' in results:
    context['people'] = results['people']
if 'topics' in results:
    context['topics'] = results['topics']
return FlipView(queryset=results['flips'], extra_context=context)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.flow, name='flow'),
```

But when I try to get into the page I'm getting the following error:

```
'FlipView' object has no attribute 'kwargs'
```

or

```
'FlipView' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Full error description:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django_countries',
 'django_extensions',
 'django_comments',
 'sparkty_app',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'compressor',
 'tagging',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'social_django',
 'registration']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\SparktyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\SparktyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  142.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\SparktyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  32.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

File "C:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\SparktyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  175.         context = self.get_context_data()

File "C:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\SparktyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get_context_data
  135.             paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)

File "C:\Users\darth\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\SparktyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in paginate_queryset
  70.         page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'FlipView' object has no attribute 'kwargs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class FlowListView(ListView):

    model = Flow # Unsure of this one, probably don't even need it.

    def get_queryset(self):
        results = cache.get(cache_key)
        if results is None:
             results = {}
             flips = pushitem.visibles.visibles()
             sort = request.GET.get('sort', '')
             if sort == 'popular':
                 flips = flips.order_by('-votes_total')
             else:
                 flips = flips.order_by('-timestamp')
             scope = request.GET.get('scope', '')
             if scope:
                 today = datetime.now()
             if scope == 'day':
                 flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year, timestamp__month=today.month, timestamp__day=today.day)
             if scope == 'month':
                 flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year, timestamp__month=today.month)
             if scope == 'year':
                  flips = flips.filter(timestamp__year=today.year)
             # Todo use UserProfile instead of User for people and add a searchfield to UserProfile (faster)
             query = request.GET.get('q', '')
             if query:
                 people = User.objects.filter(Q(username__contains=query))
                 people |= User.objects.filter(Q(first_name__contains=query))
                 people |= User.objects.filter(Q(last_name__contains=query))
                 flips = flips.filter(Q(searchfield__contains=query))
                 topics =   Tag.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=unidecode(query.lower())))
                 results['people'] = people
                 results['topics'] = topics
                 results['flips'] = flips
                 cache.set(cache_key, results)
        return results

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FlowListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = _('Flipter.com, Ask everything!')
        context['description'] = _('The world\'s largest community of opinions, made with awesome polls.')
        # This is something you'll have to do a bit differently, unsure if it will work
        results = kwargs['object_list']
        if 'people' in results:
            context['people'] = results['people']
        if 'topics' in results:
            context['topics'] = results['topics']
        return context
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', FlowListView.as_view(), name='flow-list'),
]
```